# Javascript/jQuery set cursor in editable DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cursor, contenteditable

Had a look at a few methods of moving the cursor around and cant seem to come up with a elegant / working way.

I basicly want to call a line of code to do the following psuedo code.

1. Get length of text in editable div
2. Set cursor to last letter

e.g.

this is sample text|

cursor set to where | is

How simple is this?

JsFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/v8agZ/5/

Thanks

Comment: You can use this link for an answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442460/focus-on-input-field-with-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [jCaret plugin](http://www.jquery-plugin.buss.hk/my-plugins/jquery-caret-plugin)

A [Demo](http://examplet.buss.hk/trycode/index.php?file=jQuery-jCaret-Detect-Start-Position) , Not mine

Answer (score 1):

This is a way in which you can put the cursor at the end of an **editable *div*** (adapted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513329/set-cursor-to-the-end-of-contenteditable-div)).

**HTML**

```
<div id="mydiv">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    <br />
    <br />
    consectetur adipisicing elit
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function setCursorToEnd(ele) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart(ele, ele.childNodes.length - 1);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    ele.focus();
}

var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
setCursorToEnd(mydiv);
```

If you want to use **jQuery** (that is useless in this case), you can simply get the `mydiv` element using the `$()` and `get()` methods as follows:

```
var mydiv = $("#mydiv").get(0);
setCursorToEnd(mydiv);
```